# Inputting a big structured matrix in Mathematica

Tags: matrix

Hi this is my first post and this is a problem that has bothered me a lot.

Suppose we have the $2012\times2012$ square matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}-3&1&1&1&1&1&\ldots&1&1&1&1\\1&2&1&1&1&1&\ldots&1&1&1&1\\1&1&-3&1&1&1&\ldots&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&2&1&1&\ldots&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&-3&1&\ldots&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1&2&\ldots&1&1&1&1\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ldots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\1&1&1&1&1&1&\ldots&-3&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1&1&\ldots&1&2&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1&1&\ldots&1&1&-3&1\\1&1&1&1&1&1&\ldots&1&1&1&2\end{bmatrix}$

How can I write it using *Mathematica*? Of course I need to define something like a function which will assign elements to the positions of the matrix.

Comment: You shouldn't be in such a hurry to Accept (green check-mark) an answer, as it may discourage other, potentially better answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like

```
matrix = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} /; OddQ[i] -> -3, {i_, i_} /; EvenQ[i] -> 
 2}, {2012,2012}, 1] // Normal;
```

If you are interested in the formal solution for it determinant,

```
Clear[matrix];
matrix[n_] :=  SparseArray[{{i_, i_} /; OddQ[i] -> -3, {i_, i_} /; EvenQ[i] -> 
 2}, {n, n}, 1];
```

you can start guessing a recursion from

```
Table[matrix[n] // Det, {n, 2, 32, 2}]
```

Thanks to Mr Wizard's advice you can in fact do

```
   f = Table[matrix[n] // Det, {n, 2, 32, 2}] // FindSequenceFunction;
   f[n]
```

(* (-1)^n 4^(n-1) (3 n+4)  *)

And for the Odd matrices (following R.M's request)

```
   Table[matrix[n] // Det, {n, 1, 31, 2}] //FindSequenceFunction // #[n] &
```

(*     3 (-1)^n 4^(n-1) n  *)

```
   f/@ Range[16]
   f[2012/2] // N
```

(* 3.552922584185648*10^608 *)

Comment: Ok thanks, but I need to find the determinant, how can this be done?

Comment: you type `Det[matrix]` though i) it might take a while and ii) its probably a big number

Comment: for instance for a 200x200 matrix of this type the determinant is 122127291363683260941189119017928357791687427527492255482904576

Comment: Thanks again, if I replace the {2012,2012} with {n,n} will I get the general formula of the determinant?

Comment: not trivially; you need to think then :-) and then may be ask the math.stackexchange.com people. I would think by recursion it might be possible to find the general solution.

Comment: @PapadopoulosGerogios Since the elements are exact integers, Mathematica tries to solve it symbolically and it can take forever to compute the determinant for a 2012x2012 matrix. Instead, if you are satisfied with a machine precision solution, then you can try `Det@N@matrix`. Indeed, it is a huge number: `3.552922584185394*10^608`

Comment: Less guessing if you use `FindSequenceFunction` ;-)

Comment: Why not just run the table for `{n, 1, 16, 1}`? That way your function can be used for both odd and even matrix sizes

Comment: @R.M no particular reason, but the solution is clearly less elegant.

Comment: Ha! Ok then :) $ $

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have all been great! I tried to bring the matrix to an upper triangular form and compute the determinant by just multiplying the elements of the diagonal, but something goes wrong and I needed a result from a computer program, or maybe a result of the determinant for the general case n×n.

Comment: @PapadopoulosGerogios Did you try Chris' update to his answer? It gives you a general formula...

Comment: Yes I did it! :)

Answer (score 17):

```
SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}, {12, 12}] -> {-3, 2}, Automatic, 1] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Replace `{12, 12}` with `{2012, 2012}` for the full array.

Comment: +1. And to implement your `FindSequenceFunction` hint, take a look at `a[n_] := SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}, {n, n}] -> {-3, 2}, Automatic, 1];
Partition[Table[ 2^(2 - n - Mod[n, 2]) Det[a[n]] , {n, 2, 50, 1}] , 2] // MatrixForm`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard beyond readability, any advantage of using Band?

Comment: @chris It is also about 1400 times faster for this specific problem on my system.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ah! I see your point about a better answer then ;-) Well I already had given you my vote so...

Comment: @chris My comment was *not* to slight your answer.  Your answer is more complete than mine and you were engaging the OP to discover and address his real needs, both of which merit the Accept IMHO.  Rather, I frequently encourage users to wait a day before choosing an answer as there are people in different time zones who will not even have a chance to see the question before it is "concluded" (if you will).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you may be interested that using one rule as input to a `SparseArray` is more efficient. Not sure you know that. See my answer.

Comment: @ruebenko yes, actually I did; Norbert Pozar showed me that.  I decided it was a bit esoteric for the venue.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, agreed, I just thought you might enjoy that as a side note but good that you knew.

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness sake, here is an even more efficient way to construct the `SparseArray`

```
n = 123013;
AbsoluteTiming[
 pos = Transpose[{#, #}] &[Range[n]];
 vals = ConstantArray[-3, {n}];
 vals[[2 ;; -Mod[n, 2] - 1 ;; 2]] = -2;
 SparseArray[pos -> vals, {n, n}, 1]
 ]
(*{0.009, Null}*)
AbsoluteTiming[
 SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}, {n, n}] -> {-3, 2}, Automatic, 1]
 ]
(*{0.482, Null}*)
```

Using one rule is generally a very efficient way to generate a `SparseArray`

Comment: You can make this twice as fast by using `pos = {#, #}\[Transpose] &@Range@n;
vals = ConstantArray[-3, n];` :-) (+1 btw)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you are right, why not go all the way. Fixed.

Comment: OK, I also did, that, but that seemed small compared to the `Transpose`.

Comment: Interestingly I get about a 50% speed improvement of the entire operation by using `ConstantArray` in place of `Table`, over the intermediate version.  Maybe `Table` is faster in v8?

Comment: Hm, yes this may be due to version or OS. It's sure good to have both. But an improvement of `Table` is also conceivable. Something like this can be very hard to track down to a (or several) courses.

Comment: Why not `Riffle[]` two `ConstantArray[]`s instead?

Comment: @J.M. I think were equally good. `Riffle[ConstantArray[-3, {Ceiling[n/2]}], 
 ConstantArray[2, {Floor[n/2]}]]` It's just that I often stick to simple functions that are "good" like `Part`. - The good, the bad and the ugly - (good: works with PackedArrays and compilable), (bad: either PA or compilable), (ugly: neither.)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way (with timings similar to ruebenko's):

```
 values = ArrayPad[{-3, 2}, {0, n - 2}, "Periodic"];
 diag = Transpose[Range[{n, n}]];
 SparseArray[diag -> values, {n, n}, 1]]
```

Comment: a quick note: `ArrayPad` does not return a packed array, so, it is less efficient in space.

Comment: if you see crashes, please report them to the support such that they can be fixed.

Comment: that said, the fact that some function does/can not return a packed array does not mean that it is more susceptible to crashes. Out of memory, and it's subsequent kernel shut down yes.