# Proving a recurrence in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra, proof

I have

$$j_n=\int_0^1 x^{2n} \sin(\pi x)dx.$$

How do I show that $$j_{n+1}= \frac{1}{\pi^2}(\pi- (2n+1)(2n+2)j_n)\, ?$$

I keep getting a recurring integration by parts and I can't simplify it.
Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 8):

**Integration by parts** gives

$$\int_0^1 x^k \sin(\pi x) dx = \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{k}{\pi}\int_0^1 x^{k-1} \cos(\pi x) dx$$

and

$$\int_0^1 x^k \cos(\pi x) dx = - \frac{k}{\pi}\int_0^1 x^{k-1} \sin(\pi x) dx.$$

Applying these rules in succession to $j_{n+1}$ immediately gives

$$j_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\pi} - \frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{\pi^2} j_n$$

which clearly is equal to the desired formula.

Notice that this works for any real $n \gt -1$ (so that the integrals converge).

---

Brute-force attempts at integration produce error functions (`Erf`), Dawson's integrals (`DawsonF`), or generalized hypergeometric functions (`HypergeometricPFQ`), and these do not readily simplify.  Let's try something more elementary.

Having seen that the mathematical solution above requires *two* integrations by parts, we ought to be interested in the *second* derivative of $x^{2n+2}\sin(\pi x)$:

```
D[x^(2 n + 2) Sin[Pi x], {x, 2}]
```

> $(2 n+1) (2 n+2) x^{2 n} \sin (\pi  x)-\pi ^2 x^{2 n+2} \sin (\pi  x) + \color{Red}{2 \pi  (2 n+2) x^{2 n+1} \cos (\pi  x)}$

The first two terms are exactly what we would be integrating when evaluating $(2n+1)(2n+2)j_{n} - \pi^2 j_{n+1}$ in order to check the equality we're trying to prove. The last term is a problem: how to make it go away?  Well, still motivated by integrations by parts, we ought to examine a similar derivative,

```
D[x^(2 n + 1) Sin[Pi x], x]
```

> $(2 n+1) x^{2 n} \sin (\pi  x) + \color{Red}{\pi  x^{2 n+1} \cos (\pi  x)}$

The second term is a constant multiple of what we're trying to get rid of and the first one is not worrisome: it's proportional to the integrand for $j_n$. So, an appropriate linear combination of these two derivatives ought to clear things up a bit:

```
Expand[D[x^(2 n + 2) Sin[Pi x], {x, 2}] - 2 (2 + 2 n) D[x^(2 n + 1) Sin[Pi x], x] , x]
```

> $-(2 n+1) (2 n+2) x^{2 n} \sin (\pi  x)-\pi ^2 x^{2 n+2} \sin (\pi  x)$

This can be stated in reverse: the *indefinite* integral of the result is what we differentiated, so let's just take one less derivative to find out what it is!

```
D[x^(2 n + 2) Sin[Pi x], x] - 2 (2 + 2 n) x^(2 n + 1) Sin[Pi x]
```

> $\pi  x^{2 n+2} \cos (\pi  x)-(2 n+2) x^{2 n+1} \sin (\pi  x)$

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we can find $-(2n+1)(2n+2)j_n - \pi^2 j_{n+1}$ by evaluating this antiderivative at the endpoints $0$ and $1$:

```
FullSimplify[% /. {x -> #} & /@ {0, 1} // Differences, Assumptions -> n > -1]
```

> $\{-\pi \}$

That is, these *Mathematica* manipulations have demonstrated that

$$\eqalign{
-(2n+1)(2n+2)j_n - \pi^2 j_{n+1} &= \int_0^1 \left(-(2n+1)(2n+2)x^{2n}\sin{\pi x} - \pi^2 x^{2n+2}\sin(\pi x)\right) dx \\
&= \left(\pi  x^{2 n+2} \cos (\pi  x)-(2 n+2) x^{2 n+1} \sin (\pi  x)\right)\mid_0^1 \\
&= -\pi.
}$$

This obviously is algebraically equivalent to the desired result.  But in the process we have obtained an *indefinite* integral for the integrands associated with this linear combination of $j_n$ and $j_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

I have more (mathematica) questions than answers.

Let us define

```
J[n_] := Integrate[ x^(2 n)  Sin[Pi x], {x, 0, 1}]

(* (Pi*HypergeometricPFQ[{1 + n}, {3/2, 2 + n}, -Pi^2/4])/(2 + 2*n) *)
```

and

```
Clear[JJ];
JJ[n_] :=  JJ[n]=1/Pi^2 (Pi - (2 n ) (2 n -1) JJ[n - 1]) // Simplify
JJ[0] = J[0];
```

We have

```
 Table[J[n] - JJ[n], {n, 0, 6}] // Simplify

(* {0,0,0,0,0,0,0} *)
```

which suggests the recursion is 'likely'

(Thanks to KennyColnago  for pointing out an offset in the recursion)

My question would be: why

```
  Table[J[n],{n,0,4}]//FindSequenceFunction
```

does not provide the recursion?
And I don't understand why

```
 Clear[j];  eqn = j[n] == b j[n - 1] + c /. 
 Solve[Table[J[n] == b J[n - 1] + c, {n, 1, 2}] // Simplify, {b,c}][[1]]

 Table[eqn /. j -> J, {n, 1, 3}] // Simplify
```

produces

```
(* {True,True,False} *)
```

Comment: There is an index problem. Your definition of `JJ[n_]` has `JJ[n-1]` on the right-hand side, and so should have the $n$ there as $n-1$. That is,  `JJ[n_]:= 1/Pi^2 (Pi - (2 (n-1) + 2) (2 (n-1) + 1) JJ[n - 1])`.  Thus I believe the recursion is correct.

Comment: @KennyColnago oops!!!

Comment: Why are you asking a question as an answer? You should ask a new question instead

Comment: @rm-rf I did provide a partial answer; I wanted to have a clean proof and, having been told about `FindSequenceFunction` not long ago on this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11042/inputting-a-big-structured-matrix-in-mathematica/11043#11043 I was expecting it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Quite a manual process :

Solve the indefinite integral, then calculate the definite one :

```
indefInt[n_, x_] = Simplify[Integrate[x^(2 (n)) Sin[Pi x], x],
  Assumptions -> {0 <= x <= 1, n \[Element] Integers}];

int[n_] = Assuming[n \[Element] Integers, 
    Limit[indefInt[n, x], x -> 1, Direction -> +1] - 
    Limit[indefInt[n, x], x -> 0, Direction -> -1]];
```

Now define an identity regarding the incomplete Gamma function :

```
recursion = Gamma[n_, z_] -> (n - 1) Gamma[n - 1, z] + z^(n - 1) Exp[-z];
```

Finally put everything together :

```
en = FullSimplify[int[n] /. recursion, Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}] ;

enp1 = FullSimplify[int[n + 1] /. recursion /. recursion /. recursion,
    Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}];

FullSimplify[enp1 - 1/Pi^2 (Pi - (2 n + 1) (2 n + 2) en), 
    Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}]

(* 0 *)
```

Comment: do you know why mma does not provide your closed form as the naive integration solution? Do you know why it does not find the recursion either?

Comment: @chris It gives a closed form solution for the integral but it involves hypergeometric functions and I am not aware of similar recursions.